# In my Blazor (Server App) razor page (Shared directory) I want to show a variable value that is created in another Razor Page (Pages directory).How?

Tags: data-binding, blazor, razor-pages

In the Blazor Server App Template (Shared/LoginDisplay), I want to show a variable value, that is generated in another razor page (but this time in the "pages" directory- let's say the count value in the "Counter" page). I have read some entries but realy I couldn't understand the logic how to do it. Can someone explain me that in an easy way?
I have tried in this way, but the data is not being updated, when it changes it's value. Just when I reload page manualy the data is shown in the LoginDisplay.

```
@page "/loginDisplay"

<p>Counter Value: @Pages.Counter.currentCount</p>
```

I have defined the counterCount as public static in the counter page.

Answer (score 0):

A component isn't rendered until an HTTP request is made to the route, eg `/counter`. If you increment the counter, and then navigate away the component is gone and so is the value.

If you would like to retrieve the value from `/counter`, the counter component must persist the count somewhere, and the other component `/pages` should retrieve the value from where the counter stored it.

Comment: Hello @Adam Vincent  In this case, should I create a service class and store the counter in this class? If yes what kind of Service it should be? (Singleton, Transient...?) Should I inject this service in both my pages? (1 Counter page, 2 loginDisplay page)

Comment: Yes, a counter service is appropriate.  I don't know your requirements, there are a lot of ways to store things; in memory, session state, file, database etc.  I almost always start with an in memory storage mechanism for unit testing and decide on actual persistence later.